# Full Calendar Localization : Fetching events based upon Gregorian Dates

Tags: fullcalendar

I used to save the events inside database in Gregorian Dates,  Now i am trying to make use of full calendar Localization (ar-sa).

I am displaying the calendar in lang(ar-sa), but how can i request a query to fetch only those events that falls between(start & end date time).

I already have one method,which will request database to fetch events between start & Date by using below code

```
var vsDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start;
var veDate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end;
```

the plugin making the request as follows

```
{"departmentID":"35","doctorID":0,"startDate":"٢-٢١-٢٠١٦ ٠:٠٠","endDate":"٢-٢٢-٢٠١٦ ٠:٠٠"}
```

so what will the solution to fetch the events which are saved in Gregorian dates.

shall i have to format date time into Gregorain in client side or shall i have to format datetime into Gregorian on server side ??